# VBA invocation of Shapes.AddPicture generates run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked far and wide for examples of the Shapes.AddPicture method, and it seems that the following code should work:

```
Sub TestAddPicture()

Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
"C:\Full\Path\To\BarsBoxes.png", _
False, True, 1, 1, -1, -1)

End Sub
```

This generates a runtime error 1004.  If I remove the `Call`, it doesn't compile.  I tried replacing `False` and `True` with `msoFalse` and `msoTrue`, but it doesn't solve the problem.  I also tried using 0 and 1 in place of `False` and `True`, again to no avail.

Thanks for suggestions on where the error may lie.  I am using Excel 2013 desktop app.

**Afternote:**

The same error occurs when assigning the result of AddPictures to a variable:

```
Sub TestAddPicture()
Dim s As Shape
Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture( _
"C:\Full\Path\To\BarsBoxes.png", _
False, True, 1, 1, -1, -1)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your worksheet protected?  And what's the *text* of the error message?

Comment: No, it is not protected

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: Hmmm.  Baffled.  BTW, the popup error window says "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: FYI if you remove `Call` from the first example it will compile when you also remove the parentheses around the arguments.  When not using `Call`, parentheses are typically only be used if you want to capture a return value.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and it compiles, but gives the same run-time error.  The code works on a *new* workbook, but not the existing one.  Unfortunately, I need it to work on the existing one.  But the error message is completely opaque.

Comment: Does it work on a different sheet in the same workbook?

Comment: No it does not.  I tried copying my sheets to a new workbook, but copy doesn't work if the sheets contain "ListObject" tables.  My sheets have lots of those.

Comment: Sorry I'm out of ideas/questions...

Comment: How about deleting one-by-one everything (modules, routines, references, etc.) until you get to the same configuration as a "new" workbook? (I get that error only if the file doesn't exist.)

Comment: There are very few if any of those (I assume you mean subroutines and formula cross-references?).  The problem turned out to be a display option (!!!!).  I posted what I found as the answer. Hopefully, it will help someone.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Not sure what happened to the comment that I posted as a follow-up, but I thanked you for your brainstorming.

Comment: I did see that - thanks.  Good to see you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

At least in this case, the problem turned out to be a display option for the workbook:

```
File -> Options -> Advanced
     -> Display options for this workbook
     -> For objects, show: (choices are "All" or "Nothing")
```

The above setting was set at "Nothing".  Changing it to "All" seemed to enable Insert-Pictures.

The funny thing is that I bashed my head against this just recently and posted the solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-insert-pictures-grayed-out/459bc5f8-26b6-422d-befc-a2a606105d0b).  I got the solution from [here](https://professor-excel.com/buttons-inserting-images-charts-greyed-excel)